# How to exit method from sub-method without throwing exception

Tags: c#, return

I have the following code, but I am not sure what is the right pattern to exit the `Execute()` method.

The code is working, but the `Execute()` method is too large.

```
public void Execute()
{
    // load datatable from excel
    DataTable data = new();
    try
    {
        data = ExcelReader.ToDataTable(_meta.FullPath, new() { SheetName = _sheetName });
    }
    // these errors are fine, but the dataset is not relevant and we want exit the execution
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("HeaderRowIndex")) return;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("Parameter 'sheet'")) return;
    }

    // execute logic on dataset
    // ..
}
```

I would like to move the `load data` part of the code into separate method like this, but then I don't know how to end the execution.

```
public void Execute()
{
    // load data
    DataTable data = new();
    LoadData();

    // execute logic on dataset
    // ...
}

private DataTable LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        data = ExcelReader.ToDataTable(_meta.FullPath, new() { SheetName = _sheetName });
    }
    // these errors are fine, but the dataset is not relevant and we want exit the execution => but how?
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("HeaderRowIndex")) return; // will return to Execute() method, but not exit it.
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("Parameter 'sheet'")) return; // will return to Execute() method, but not exit it.
    }
}
```

I think this is very common issue, so what is the recommended way to handle this requirement? Should I create some returning object from the `LoadData` method, for example

```
class LoadDataResult
{
    public DataTable data {get; set};
    public bool IsRelevant {get; set};
}

dataResult = LoadData()
if (!dataResult.IsRelevant) return;
```

or it is an overkill and easier solution exist (to not populate program with these result objects)?

Comment: `DataTable data = LoadData();  .... do the stuff...`? I'm unclear as to what the issue is. Execution will end when there are no more statements to run or `return` is hit.

Comment: Why not simply return `null` DataTable from LoadData?

Comment: if you declare _private DataTable LoadData()_ then you should return a DataTable or null. Then it is easy on the Execute method check the return value and exit if null

Comment: private Tuple<bool,DataTable> LoadData(){}
return if you want to finish in the Item1 of the tuple and the data in the Item2

Comment: Without these result object, you can create another Execute method and put it in the end of LoadData like a matryoshka

Comment: `null` is a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return data in the output parameter and return result of data loading as a primary method output (true for successful load, false for error that is fine):

```
 private bool TryLoadData(out DataTable data)
 {
    data = null;

    try
    {
        data = ExcelReader.ToDataTable(
           _meta.FullPath, new() { SheetName = _sheetName });
        return true; // loading succeeded
    }        
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        when (e.Message.Contains("HeaderRowIndex"))
    {         
        // loading failed, continue to Execute method
        return false;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        when (e.Message.Contains("Parameter 'sheet'"))
    {
        // loading failed, continue to Execute method
        return false;
    }

    // otherwise exception propagates to Execute method
 }
```

Usage:

```
public void Execute()
{
    if (TryLoadData(out var data)
    {
       // execute logic on dataset
    }
    else
    {
       // error, but not exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would think about what you are trying to return. In your catch's you can log the error but you don't need to return.  All code will flow back to the previous method that called it regardless if it returns or not.  You only need to return if you need to pass a value back up to the previous calling method.  Otherwise, you can just leave it be!

Comment: The issue is that they want to return from the `Execute` method immediately after calling the `LoadData` if it logs an error and basically skip the logic that comes after it in `Execute`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).